# amember pro integrate with joomla

Tags: joomla, integration, joomla1.5

how to integrate amember pro with joomla. Please suggest an idea, more importantly I want to know how the subscription process works in amember pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a component and modules that you can install to integrate with Joomla.
See this thread http://amember.com/forum/showthread.php?t=4721

how the subscription process works in amember pro
- users subscribe and pay subscription free. PayPal supports subscriptions and does renewals automatically. Upon receiving payment PayPal sends you and IPN (you will have to set it up, check with amember pro what is the IPN url). Certain page on your website will recieve the IPN Message from PayPal and renew the subscription. If users does not pay, will get blocked.

Check this one out! Take your time and play with the demo on this one http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/paid-membership-a-subscriptions/7591

Check this page out, you might be able to find alternative
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/paid-membership-a-subscriptions